# How to get a list of filepaths to all external files used in Blender project?

Tags: python, path

Let's say I have a very complex Blender project with a lot of external data, such as images, geometry cache files, VDB sequences, text scripts, and maybe something else I don't even know about. How can I get a list of filepaths to all of the external data files loaded to the project?
For several internal reasons I have to avoid using pack/unpack external data option.
I know there are such operators as `bpy.ops.file.make_paths_absolute()` which somehow iterate through paths and make them absolute or relative, but those are not Python operators, so I can not read their code.
I tried to search in `bpy.path`, but could not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all library data-block

```
import bpy

cls = type(bpy.data.objects)

for attr in dir(bpy.data):
    collections = getattr(bpy.data, attr)
    if isinstance(collections, cls):
        for data_block in collections:
            if hasattr(data_block, "library") and data_block.library:
                print(f'[{data_block.__class__}] {data_block.name} :  {data_block.library.filepath}')
```

Find Images filepath

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Image

cls = type(bpy.data.objects)

for attr in dir(bpy.data):
    collections = getattr(bpy.data, attr)
    if isinstance(collections, cls):
        for data_block in collections:
            if hasattr(data_block, "library") and data_block.library:
                print(f'[{data_block.__class__}] {data_block.name} :  {data_block.library.filepath}')

            if isinstance(data_block, Image):
                print(f'Image :  {data_block.filepath}')
```

##### This should be what you want

```
import bpy

cls = type(bpy.data.objects)

for attr in dir(bpy.data):
    collections = getattr(bpy.data, attr)
    if isinstance(collections, cls):
        for data_block in collections:
            if hasattr(data_block, "library") and data_block.library:
                print(f'Data-Block Library [{data_block.__class__}] {data_block.name} :  {data_block.library.filepath}')

            if hasattr(data_block, "filepath") and data_block.filepath:
                print(f'[{data_block.__class__}] :  {data_block.filepath}')
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems it finds all paths. Some minor addjustments are needed to convert relative paths into absolute ones. Especially those starting with `"//..\\..\\..\\"`  because Blender `bpy.path.abspath()` doesn't replace this syntax with actual parent folders. But this can be easily done either with `pathlib` module or by running `bpy.ops.file.make_paths_absolute()` before the code you provided. As far as these conditions were not written in the question, your code totally corresponds to the question.